# ZTE Blade can't maintain a wifi connection

Tags: wi-fi, cyanogenmod

I have a ZTE Blade with Android 2.3.7 (CyanogenMod 7.1). Recently, when I try to connect to a wifi network (even one that worked before this problem started) it starts to connect, tries to autenticate, and then disconnects.

Here a part of the logcat

```
12-03 00:18:23.370: DEBUG/WifiStateTracker(191): Reset connections and stopping DHCP
12-03 00:18:23.530: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:23.530: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:23.530: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): Trying to associate with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c (SSID='Lambratone' freq=2412 MHz)
12-03 00:18:23.530: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=3
12-03 00:18:23.540: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:23.540: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): Trying to associate with 38:22:9d:fc:6d:20 (SSID='FASTWEB-1-38229DFC6D20' freq=2412 MHz)
12-03 00:18:23.540: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=3
12-03 00:18:23.550: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:23.550: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0
12-03 00:18:23.560: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:23.560: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=0
12-03 00:18:23.560: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:23.560: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=0
12-03 00:18:23.560: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys]
12-03 00:18:23.560: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0]
12-03 00:18:23.700: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=4
12-03 00:18:23.700: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): Associated with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c
12-03 00:18:23.710: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=4
12-03 00:18:23.710: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): No network configuration found for the current AP
12-03 00:18:23.710: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0
12-03 00:18:23.710: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=4]
12-03 00:18:23.710: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0]
12-03 00:18:23.710: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=4
12-03 00:18:23.710: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): Associated with 00:00:00:00:00:00
12-03 00:18:23.720: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:23.720: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0
12-03 00:18:23.720: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:23.720: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=0
12-03 00:18:23.720: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:23.720: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=0
12-03 00:18:23.720: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys]
12-03 00:18:23.720: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0]
12-03 00:18:23.820: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=2
12-03 00:18:23.820: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=2
12-03 00:18:24.380: DEBUG/WifiStateTracker(191): Disabling interface
12-03 00:18:24.400: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): New network state is DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:24.400: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:24.400: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> ASSOCIATED
12-03 00:18:24.400: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: ASSOCIATED ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:24.400: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): New network state is DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:24.400: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:24.500: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=2
12-03 00:18:24.500: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=2]
12-03 00:18:24.520: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> SCANNING
12-03 00:18:26.000: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:26.000: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): Trying to associate with 38:22:9d:fc:6d:20 (SSID='FASTWEB-1-38229DFC6D20' freq=2412 MHz)
12-03 00:18:26.000: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=3
12-03 00:18:26.010: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:26.010: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): Trying to associate with 38:22:9d:fc:6d:20 (SSID='FASTWEB-1-38229DFC6D20' freq=2412 MHz)
12-03 00:18:26.010: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=3
12-03 00:18:26.020: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:26.030: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:26.030: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=0
12-03 00:18:26.030: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:26.030: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=0
12-03 00:18:26.039: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:26.039: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys]
12-03 00:18:26.039: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): New network state is DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:26.049: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0
12-03 00:18:26.049: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0]
12-03 00:18:26.049: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: SCANNING ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:26.130: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(191): wakeWhenReadyLocked(26)
12-03 00:18:26.130: INFO/power(191): *** set_screen_state 1
12-03 00:18:26.130: ERROR/Sensors(191): mSensors[1]->enable(4, 1)
12-03 00:18:26.160: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=4
12-03 00:18:26.160: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): No network configuration found for the current AP
12-03 00:18:26.160: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0
12-03 00:18:26.160: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=4
12-03 00:18:26.160: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): Associated with 00:00:00:00:00:00
12-03 00:18:26.160: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=4
12-03 00:18:26.160: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): Associated with 00:00:00:00:00:00
12-03 00:18:26.170: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=4]
12-03 00:18:26.170: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0]
12-03 00:18:26.170: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> ASSOCIATED
12-03 00:18:26.170: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: ASSOCIATED ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:26.180: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:26.180: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0
12-03 00:18:26.180: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:26.180: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=0
12-03 00:18:26.180: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:26.180: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=0
12-03 00:18:26.180: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys]
12-03 00:18:26.180: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0]
12-03 00:18:26.180: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): New network state is DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:26.180: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:26.180: ERROR/Sensors(191): mSensors[2]->enable(0, 1)
12-03 00:18:26.180: INFO/AKMD2(142): akmd2 : Compass Opened.
12-03 00:18:26.280: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=2
12-03 00:18:26.280: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=2
12-03 00:18:26.340: DEBUG/WifiService(191): ACTION_SCREEN_ON
12-03 00:18:26.480: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=2
12-03 00:18:26.480: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=2]
12-03 00:18:26.480: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> SCANNING
12-03 00:18:26.570: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(191): Screen about to return, flinger = 0x95878
12-03 00:18:27.850: DEBUG/SettingsAppWidgetProvider(939): Widget is from a previous version... Let's update
12-03 00:18:27.850: DEBUG/SettingsAppWidgetProvider(939): No instances yet... Wait for at least one instance to exist before adding global settings
12-03 00:18:27.980: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:27.980: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): Trying to associate with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c (SSID='Lambratone' freq=2412 MHz)
12-03 00:18:27.980: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3
12-03 00:18:27.980: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:27.980: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): Trying to associate with 38:22:9d:fc:6d:20 (SSID='FASTWEB-1-38229DFC6D20' freq=2412 MHz)
12-03 00:18:27.980: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=3
12-03 00:18:27.980: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [Trying to associate with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c (SSID='Lambratone' freq=2412 MHz)]
12-03 00:18:27.980: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3]
12-03 00:18:27.990: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: SCANNING ==> ASSOCIATING
12-03 00:18:27.990: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:27.990: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): Trying to associate with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c (SSID='Lambratone' freq=2412 MHz)
12-03 00:18:27.990: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=3
12-03 00:18:28.020: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:28.020: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=0
12-03 00:18:28.020: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:28.020: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=0
12-03 00:18:28.020: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:28.020: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys]
12-03 00:18:28.020: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): New network state is DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:28.020: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=0
12-03 00:18:28.020: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=0]
12-03 00:18:28.030: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:28.030: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=0
12-03 00:18:28.030: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:28.030: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=0
12-03 00:18:28.030: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: ASSOCIATING ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:28.030: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:28.030: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys]
12-03 00:18:28.040: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=0
12-03 00:18:28.040: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=0]
12-03 00:18:28.050: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): New network state is DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:28.050: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:28.060: WARN/InputManagerService(191): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@407ae948
12-03 00:18:28.170: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=4
12-03 00:18:28.170: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): Associated with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c
12-03 00:18:28.170: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=4
12-03 00:18:28.170: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): Associated with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c
12-03 00:18:28.170: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=4
12-03 00:18:28.170: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=4]
12-03 00:18:28.170: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> ASSOCIATED
12-03 00:18:28.180: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): Associated with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c
12-03 00:18:28.180: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [Associated with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c]
12-03 00:18:28.200: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=5
12-03 00:18:28.200: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=5
12-03 00:18:28.210: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=5
12-03 00:18:28.210: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=5]
12-03 00:18:28.210: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: ASSOCIATED ==> FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE
12-03 00:18:28.230: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=5
12-03 00:18:28.240: WARN/wpa_supplicant(914): WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC when using TPTK - ignoring TPTK
12-03 00:18:28.240: WARN/wpa_supplicant(914): WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC - dropping packet
12-03 00:18:28.240: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=6
12-03 00:18:28.240: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): WPA: Key negotiation completed with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
12-03 00:18:28.250: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=7
12-03 00:18:28.250: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c completed (reauth) [id=0 id_str=]
12-03 00:18:28.250: WARN/wpa_supplicant(15251): WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC when using TPTK - ignoring TPTK
12-03 00:18:28.250: WARN/wpa_supplicant(15251): WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC - dropping packet
12-03 00:18:29.400: DEBUG/WifiStateTracker(191): Reset connections and stopping DHCP
12-03 00:18:30.410: DEBUG/WifiStateTracker(191): Disabling interface
12-03 00:18:30.630: DEBUG/dalvikvm(939): GC_CONCURRENT freed 611K, 50% free 3450K/6855K, external 1307K/1504K, paused 4ms+9ms
12-03 00:18:35.520: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1172): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 49% free 2772K/5379K, external 477K/989K, paused 59ms
12-03 00:18:38.210: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): Authentication with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c timed out.
12-03 00:18:38.210: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=0
12-03 00:18:38.210: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=2
12-03 00:18:38.210: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): Authentication with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c timed out.
12-03 00:18:38.210: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=0
12-03 00:18:38.210: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=2
12-03 00:18:38.210: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [Authentication with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c timed out.]
12-03 00:18:38.210: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=0]
12-03 00:18:38.210: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:38.220: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=2]
12-03 00:18:38.220: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> SCANNING
12-03 00:18:38.280: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:38.280: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0
12-03 00:18:38.280: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:38.280: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=0
12-03 00:18:38.280: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:38.280: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0
12-03 00:18:38.280: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys]
12-03 00:18:38.280: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0]
12-03 00:18:38.290: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): New network state is DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:38.300: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: SCANNING ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:38.380: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=2
12-03 00:18:39.870: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:39.870: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:39.870: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): Trying to associate with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c (SSID='Lambratone' freq=2412 MHz)
12-03 00:18:39.870: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3
12-03 00:18:39.880: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
12-03 00:18:39.880: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): Trying to associate with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c (SSID='Lambratone' freq=2412 MHz)
12-03 00:18:39.880: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=3
12-03 00:18:39.880: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): Trying to associate with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c (SSID='Lambratone' freq=2412 MHz)
12-03 00:18:39.890: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3
12-03 00:18:39.910: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:39.910: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=0
12-03 00:18:39.910: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:39.910: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=0
12-03 00:18:39.920: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [Trying to associate with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c (SSID='Lambratone' freq=2412 MHz)]
12-03 00:18:39.920: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3]
12-03 00:18:39.920: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> ASSOCIATING
12-03 00:18:39.930: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:39.930: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=0
12-03 00:18:39.930: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys]
12-03 00:18:39.930: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=0]
12-03 00:18:39.940: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:39.940: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=0
12-03 00:18:39.940: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:39.940: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=0
12-03 00:18:39.940: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
12-03 00:18:39.940: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=0
12-03 00:18:39.940: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys]
12-03 00:18:39.940: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=0]
12-03 00:18:39.950: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): New network state is DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:39.950: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: ASSOCIATING ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:39.960: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): New network state is DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:39.960: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> DISCONNECTED
12-03 00:18:40.070: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=4
12-03 00:18:40.070: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): Associated with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c
12-03 00:18:40.070: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=4
12-03 00:18:40.070: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): Associated with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c
12-03 00:18:40.070: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=4
12-03 00:18:40.070: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): Associated with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c
12-03 00:18:40.070: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=4]
12-03 00:18:40.070: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [Associated with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c]
12-03 00:18:40.070: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> ASSOCIATED
12-03 00:18:40.090: INFO/wpa_supplicant(914): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=5
12-03 00:18:40.100: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=5
12-03 00:18:40.100: INFO/wpa_supplicant(15251): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=5
12-03 00:18:40.100: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(191): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=3 state=5]
12-03 00:18:40.100: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(191): Changing supplicant state: ASSOCIATED ==> FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE
12-03 00:18:40.120: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=5
12-03 00:18:40.120: WARN/wpa_supplicant(914): WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC when using TPTK - ignoring TPTK
12-03 00:18:40.120: WARN/wpa_supplicant(914): WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC - dropping packet
12-03 00:18:40.120: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=6
12-03 00:18:40.120: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): WPA: Key negotiation completed with 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
12-03 00:18:40.120: WARN/wpa_supplicant(15251): WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC when using TPTK - ignoring TPTK
12-03 00:18:40.120: WARN/wpa_supplicant(15251): WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC - dropping packet
12-03 00:18:40.120: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=7
12-03 00:18:40.120: INFO/wpa_supplicant(268): CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 94:44:52:ef:dd:7c completed (reauth) [id=0 id_str=]
```

How can I fix this? I can't refalsh the ROM since wifi doesn't work and my contacts aren't syncronized, and I don't want to lose the new contacts I added.

Comment: Have you rebooted?  Have you tried clearing all the remembered networks and setting them up again?  You can also easily back up your contacts without needing to sync them :P

Comment: Yes, already tried to reboot and to delete the network and re add them.. Any other option other than reflash?(hoping that that works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend installing installing "MyBackup Pro" from android market and backup everything to the SD card or internet, via 3g(or similar).

Then i would do a hard reset of the phone. I guess it would be something like: settings -> privacy -> factory data reset.

If this doesnt work, i would reinstall to a standard rom with the usb cable connected to a computer.

If it still doesnt work with a standard rom, there might be a hardware problem. If the standard rom works, you can try to install the newest version of CyanogenMod.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but the solution is to set a static ip in advanced wifi settings.
My blade did the same connect/obtaining ip address/disconnect thing and after some research i found that it depended on the rom/router combination.
For instance with cm7 and the bt homehub 2 router a static ip was needed, but with the blademix365 rom it was not.
Cm7 was fine with netgear routers.
I think its to do with the network stack baked into the roms, some routers have very flaky  dhcp software and just dont work with dynamic ips from some roms.
hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I was this sissue, my ZTE Blade A6 connects 5 min and disconnect other 3, and so on, and I found other solution.

Try this:

The ADSL modems has two or more  WLAN radios, mine one have four, and I did activate the second oner, put a name, password, and other parameters, and save it.

After that you can see the another WiFi signal in your smartphone, tablet or Smart TV, and if you select it you will see that the power and the stability are diferent.

For my the second WLAN did solve my inestability problem wifi signal, now I have a good and very stable WiFi signal, my problem are solved. Try it.

Grettings.